# Control Panel forms not saving

Tags: control-panel, server, hosting

I am experiencing an odd issue. Randomly, form submissions within the control panel are not actually saving anything and redirecting me to the CP home. This happens with regular channel entry editing, Low Variables, Low Reorder, CE Cache... doesn't seem to matter what is getting saved. About 40% of the time, the form submission takes, and works as expected.

This only happens in production. It is hosted in a multi-instance environment (PagodaBox). I thought perhaps it had something to do with each request going to a different instance... but they are all sharing the same database.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it still do this if you set `Process form data in Secure Mode?` in  `Admin >> Security and Privacy >> Security and Sessions`

I have noticed this if I try and submit a form twice without any sort of page reload in between. Although not ideal, turning off the above fixed the issue for me.